# display a user's first name in a message box

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble figuring out how to identify only the first name of the user in a message box using VBA.
I have a code to prompt a message box on workbook open to allow administrative access according to the user's name with `application.username`

I want to make it a bit more personalized with just the first name of the user with a greeting. I know you can easily do this with a formula using `left()` and `find()` but I'm unsure how to translate that within VBA.

thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub hgfds()
    MsgBox Split(Application.UserName, " ")(0)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You do not need the space,     `MsgBox Split(Application.UserName)(0)` would do the same.

Comment: Welcome :). This works like this in plenty of languages as well. E.g. C#.

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew it was going to much more simplistic than I imagined (could've used 1 more snooze this morning). Will mark as answered, however one question to @Vityata, do you not require the delimiter `" "` because it's a space rather than a comma, etc?

Comment: @Awill, you do not require delimiter, if the delimiter is space. Doesn't matter how many spaces. If it is comma, or anything else, you require one.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks so much for the clarification and help!

Answer (score 3):

You use the ampersand to concatenate strings in VBA, for example.

```
Dim Name As String
Name = "Hello " & application.username
MsgBox Name
```

You can use a [split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function to split by a space to only get their first name.